# UITableViewCell hide separator using separatorInset fails in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11

This is the code I used to hide the separator for a single UITableViewCell prior to iOS 11:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {


        // Remove separator inset
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0, 0)];
        }

        // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
        }

        // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
            [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0, 0)];
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the separator is hidden for the first row in every section. I don't want to get rid of the separators completely - only for certain rows.

In iOS 11, the above code does not work. The content of the cell is pushed completely to the right.

Is there a way to accomplish the task of hiding the separator for a single UITableViewCell in iOS 11?

Let me clarify in advance that I do know that I can hide the separator for the entire UITableView with the following code (to hopefully avoid answers instructing me to do this):

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

EDIT: Also to clarify after a comment below, the code does exactly the same thing if I include the setSeparatorInset line at all. So even with only that one line, the content of the cell is pushed all the way to the right.

Comment: it probably has to do with setting the layout margins the way you did. Did you try removing that block of code?

Comment: it does exactly the same thing if I include the setSeparatorInset line at all. So even with only that one line, the content of the cell is pushed all the way to the right.

Comment: @SAHM did you do anything else with your tableView or cells? Your code works perfectly on my Simulator iPhone8 iOS 11. https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2WZ5.png

Comment: I suggest to set separatorStyle as UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone then add custom separator in your custom cell, provide also hide and show methods in the .h to hide and show custom separator.
It's very easy and i always do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not keen on adding a custom separator to your `UITableViewCell` I can show you yet another workaround to consider.

#### How it works

Because the color of the separator is defined on the `UITableView` level there is no clear way to change it per `UITableViewCell` instance. It was not intended by Apple and the only thing you can do is to hack it.

The first thing you need is to get access to the separator view. You can do it with this small extension.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var separatorView: UIView? {
        return subviews .min { $0.frame.size.height < $1.frame.size.height }
    }
}
```

When you have an access to the separator view, you have to configure your `UITableView` appropriately. First, set the global color of all separators to `.clear` (but **don't** disable them!)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear
}
```

Next, set the separator color for each cell. You can set a different color for each of them, depends on you.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SeparatorCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.separatorView?.backgroundColor = .red

    return cell
}
```

Finally, for every first row in the section, set the separator color to `.clear`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.separatorView?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

#### Why it works

First, let's consider the structure of the `UITableViewCell`. If you print out the `subviews` of your cell you will see the following output.

```
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7ff77e604f50; frame = (0 0; 328 43.6667); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000058d50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400022a660>>
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7ff77e4010c0; frame = (15 43.5; 360 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000223740>>
<UIButton: 0x7ff77e403b80; frame = (0 0; 22 22); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000222500>>
```

As you can see there is a view which holds the content, the separator, and the accessory button. From this perspective, you only need to access the separator view and modify it's background. Unfortunately, it's not so easy.

Let's take a look at the same `UITableViewCell` in the view debugger. As you can see, there are **two** separator views. You need to access the bottom one which is not present when the `willDisplay:` is called. This is where the second hacky part comes to play.

[image: structorue of the table view cell]

When you will inspect these two elements, you will see that the first (from the top) has a background color set to `nil` and the second has a background color set to the value you have specified for entire `UITableView`. In this case, the separator with the color covers the separator without the color.

To solve the issue we have to "reverse" the situation. We can set the color of all separators to `.clear` which will uncover the one we have an access to. Finally, we can set the background color of the accessible separator to what is desired.

Comment: Wow - great answer! I would still be interested if you find a way to do this with insets because there are times I need show a full line as opposed to hiding the line, so I think it would be good to have this flexibility in general. I wonder if this option to change the line width without killing the content of the cell is still somehow available. But yours was a really clever answer to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by hiding all separators via `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`. Then modify your `UITableViewCell` subclass to something as follows:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    var separatorLine: UIView?
    ...
}
```

Add the following to the method body of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`:

```
if cell.separatorLine == nil {
    // Create the line.
    let singleLine = UIView()
    singleLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    singleLine.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Add the line to the cell's content view.
    cell.contentView.addSubview(singleLine)

    let singleLineConstraints = [singleLine.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
                                 singleLine.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor),
                                 singleLine.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -1),
                                 singleLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)]
    cell.contentView.addConstraints(singleLineConstraints)

    cell.separatorLine = singleLine
}

cell.separatorLine?.isHidden = [Boolean which determines if separator should be displayed]
```

This code is in Swift, so do as you must for the Objective-C translation and make sure to continue your version checking. In my tests I don't need to use the `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAt:)` at all, instead everything is in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Just posted an edit that mimics the separator inset and gives full cell-level control. If you wanted to make a faster implementation you could possibly use CoreGraphics to do some of the drawing, but this isn't too much more expensive than the UIKit implementation.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate it. I would still prefer to find a way to suppress the separator if possible, though. This would be a last resort.

Comment: Still looking for a better solution. They changed layout code in iOS 11, specifically to do with margins and such. That’s why this is broken now.

Comment: I've tried a couple different things with the safe area but I haven't been able to get it. Will post if I do.

Answer (score 1):

Best way IMO is just to add a simple UIView with 1pt height.
I wrote the following protocol which enables you to use it in any UITableViewCell you like:

```
// Base protocol requirements
protocol SeperatorTableViewCellProtocol: class {
    var seperatorView: UIView! {get set}
    var hideSeperator: Bool! { get set }
    func configureSeperator()
}

// Specify the separator is of a UITableViewCell type and default separator configuration method
extension SeperatorTableViewCellProtocol where Self: UITableViewCell {
    func configureSeperator() {
        hideSeperator = true
        seperatorView = UIView()
        seperatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: .WhiteThree)
        contentView.insertSubview(seperatorView, at: 0)

        // Just constraint seperatorView to contentView
        seperatorView.setConstant(edge: .height, value: 1.0)
        seperatorView.layoutToSuperview(.bottom)
        seperatorView.layoutToSuperview(axis: .horizontally)

        seperatorView.isHidden = hideSeperator
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
// Implement the protocol with custom cell
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, SeperatorTableViewCellProtocol {

    // MARK: SeperatorTableViewCellProtocol impl'
    var seperatorView: UIView!
    var hideSeperator: Bool! {
        didSet {
            guard let seperatorView = seperatorView else {
                return
            }
            seperatorView.isHidden = hideSeperator
        }
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureSeperator()
        hideSeperator = false
    }
}
```

And that's all. You are able to customize any UITableViewCell subclass to use a separator.

Set separator visibility from tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath by:

```
cell.hideSeperator = false / true
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I appreciate it. I would still prefer to find a way to suppress the separator if possible, though. This would be a last resort.

Comment: Glad i could help. :-) 
If you end up finding another solution, it'll be interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed this pattern once. Over the years I adjusted it. Just today I had to remove the `directionalLayoutMargins` part to be able to make it work. Now My function looks like this:

```swift
    func adjustCellSeparatorInsets(at indexPath: IndexPath,
                                   for modelCollection: ModelCollection,
                                   numberOfLastSeparatorsToHide: Int) {

        guard modelCollection.isInBounds(indexPath) else { return }

        let model = modelCollection[indexPath]
        var insets = model.separatorInsets
        let lastSection = modelCollection[modelCollection.sectionCount - 1]
        let shouldHideSeparator = indexPath.section == modelCollection.sectionCount - 1
            && indexPath.row >= lastSection.count - numberOfLastSeparatorsToHide

        // Don't show the separator for the last N rows of the last section
        if shouldHideSeparator {
            insets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 9999, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        }

        // removing separator inset
        separatorInset = insets.edgeInsets

        // prevent the cell from inheriting the tableView's margin settings
        preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
```

See [this link](https://github.com/Blackjacx/Source/blob/bca9860eccb4843f0edb790ec7cbd873fe3abecf/Source/Classes/UITableViewCell%2BExtensions.swift#L13-L35) if you prefer to inspect it on Github.

The PR of the removal with an explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/Blackjacx/Source/pull/31).

Answer (score -1):

Actually when i work with UITableView, i always create custom cell class and for separators and usually make my own separator as UIView with height 1 and left and right constraints, in Your case make those steps:
1. Create custom cell.
2. Add UIView as separator.
3. Link this separator to your custom class.
4. Add hideSeparator method to your class.

```
-(void)hideSeparator{
   self.separator.hidden == YES;
}
```

5. Hide the separator for any cell you want.

Hope that solves your question.